# Filtering Overlapping Dates within Set Date Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, filtering, spreadsheet

I have a couple of questions I need for a semi-annual report:

I have a list of interns, each with their own start and end dates of service. I am looking to filter the list of those who worked within a given range of dates. I want any intern who has their term of service that overlaps with the range dates.

I am also looking to calculate how many weeks + months they worked within the same range of dates.

[Here is the Spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SViL8twheBPCxYbda70jD6YYEuRkm8dzCg3-pirItVc/edit#gid=0)

I have tried your basic filter with date ranges, but I am not able to figure out the overlapping aspect of the list. For example, if the date range is 2021-2022, and an intern worked from 2020-2022, it would not filter it, as the start date is outside of the range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the time period in weeks and months, or are you looking for how many weeks and months were in the time period? (Eg. if an intern worked from Oct 15 to Dec 15 that would be a time period of 2 months, but in the time period there are 3 months: Oct, Nov, Dec)

Comment: Also, can an intern have more than one entry because there is a gap in their attendance? In your sheet, Marlo has two entries but they are both the same? This would make the question more difficult.

Comment: @Markus I am looking to calculate for how many weeks and months in the given time period :)

Comment: @TomSharpe my apologies, that was a typo, there will not be any intern with multiple dates.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will work for all 3 columns:

```
=FILTER(
    {
    A2:A,
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        1+
        TRUNC(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C<G2,C2:C,G2)-43101)/7)-
        TRUNC(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B>F2,B2:B,F2)-43101)/7)
    ),
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        1+
        DATEDIF(
            ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B>F2,B2:B,F2)),
            ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C<G2,C2:C,G2)),
            "M"
        )
       )
    },
    ARRAYFORMULA((IF(C2:C>G2,G2,C2:C) - IF(B2:B<F2,F2,B2:B)) >0 )
)
```

For calculating the months the formula uses the `DATEDIF` function.

For calculating the weeks, I am choosing as reference an arbitrarily defined week zero starting on Monday, 2018-01-01 (day 43101 in the Network Time Protocol).

[Link to Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11J6_0S0zDbWPAsiWQYUsKibHvt5W_frjES9uNCKVGqQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

**Check for Overlap**

For a simple pull-down formula to check if each intern has any time overlapping the range, use the standard Overlap Formula:

```
Min(end1,end2)-Max(start1,start2)
```

which gives

```
=if(min(C2,G$2)>=max(B2,F$2),"Yes","No")
```

or for an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(lambda(start,end,if(if(end<G2,end,G2)>=if(start>F2,start,F2),"Yes","No"))
(filter(B2:B,A2:A<>""),filter(C2:C,A2:A<>"")))
```

---

**Months**

@Markus's approach is perfect, but for an alternative one could use:

```
=datedif(eomonth(max(B2,F$2),-1)+1,eomonth(min(C2,$G$2),0)+1,"M")
```

(for Jeremy as an example) in other words dial the start date back to the first of the month and the finish date forwards to the start of the next month and use Datedif to get the overlap in full months. The point of this is that it could be adapted for weeks as well.

With the lookup on names in column I2:

```
=datedif(eomonth(max(xlookup(I2,A$2:A$8,B$2:B$8),F$2),-1)+1,eomonth(min(xlookup(I2,A$2:A$8,C$2:C$8),$G$2),0)+1,"M")
```

or as an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(lambda(rNames,Names,start,end,datedif(eomonth(if(xlookup(rnames,Names,start)>F2,xlookup(rnames,Names,start),F2),-1)+1,eomonth(if(xlookup(rnames,Names,end)<G2,xlookup(rnames,Names,end),G2),0)+1,"M"))
(filter(I2:I,I2:I<>""),filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""),filter(B2:B,A2:A<>""),filter(C2:C,A2:A<>"")))
```

**Weeks**

You have a few options here.

(1) Having found the number of complete or partial months of overlap, just divide the number of days in those months by seven to get corresponding number of weeks:

```
=ArrayFormula(lambda(rNames,Names,start,end,quotient(datedif(eomonth(if(xlookup(rnames,Names,start)>F2,xlookup(rnames,Names,start),F2),-1)+1,eomonth(if(xlookup(rnames,Names,end)<G2,xlookup(rnames,Names,end),G2),0)+1,"D"),7))
(filter(I2:I,I2:I<>""),filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""),filter(B2:B,A2:A<>""),filter(C2:C,A2:A<>"")))
```

(2) Use the same logic as for months to get number of partial or complete working weeks of overlap:

```
=ArrayFormula(lambda(rNames,Names,start,end,quotient(datedif(if(xlookup(rnames,Names,start)>F2,xlookup(rnames,Names,start),F2)-weekday(if(xlookup(rnames,Names,start)>F2,xlookup(rnames,Names,start),F2)),if(xlookup(rnames,Names,end)<G2,xlookup(rnames,Names,end),G2)+7-weekday(if(xlookup(rnames,Names,end)<G2,xlookup(rnames,Names,end),G2),3),"D"),7))
(filter(I2:I,I2:I<>""),filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""),filter(B2:B,A2:A<>""),filter(C2:C,A2:A<>"")))
```

(3) Just get number of complete weeks of overlap by dividing number of days by 7:

```
=ArrayFormula(lambda(rNames,Names,start,end,quotient(datedif(if(xlookup(rnames,Names,start)>F2,xlookup(rnames,Names,start),F2),if(xlookup(rnames,Names,end)<G2,xlookup(rnames,Names,end),G2),"D"),7))
(filter(I2:I,I2:I<>""),filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""),filter(B2:B,A2:A<>""),filter(C2:C,A2:A<>"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the DATEDIF function. It is more straightforward / short than my original approach and should therefore be used. I just included it in my answer.

Comment: This is incredible!!!  Out of curiosity, how could I adapt this to count weeks?

Comment: I'm thinking use the same method as months but dial the start date back to the start of the working week and the finish date forwards to the start of the next working week. Of course you could just calculate the days overlap and divide by 7.